# Provisioning fails due to company policy

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I wanted to try provisioning my app resources in Azure using the TeamsToolkit, but it fails creating the resource group since my company requires 4 tags to be added.

Is there a way to tell the toolkit to either add those tags or create the resource group myself and make it aware of it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing with Teams Toolkit and didn't find any option to configure the resources (choose existing or setup policy).

Following the doc also there's no mention about doing such - [Deploy your app to azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-app-bot?tabs=vscode#deploy-your-app-to-azure) and even on the [market place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension#:%7E:text=%20Getting%20started%20%201%20Create%20your%20project.,Provisioning%20and%20Deployment.%20Provisioning%20creates%20all...%20More%20) it is not
mention that we can configure it.